# Return value of cin not 0 upon pressing Enter

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i=0;
    int a[100];

    while(cin>>a[i]){i++;}
    cout<<i;

    return 0;
}
```

This code is used for getting an array input without knowing its size previously. Note that I used `a[100]` since the bounds are given and the number of elements does not exceed 100.

This worked fine in all of the compilers except for Code::Blocks, where the loop goes on even after pressing `ENTER`. Shouldn't the condition of the `while` loop be false upon pressing `ENTER` on the keyboard on all compilers?

Is there any workaround for this or any other way to get array inputs without knowing its size?

Comment: Formatted input, by default, skips whitespace so it ignores your enter key. If this is for an online submission where input is redirected to your program then it will work because the end of that input will be marked with EOF.

Comment: Please do not use CodeBlocks for compilation . Better use Visual Studio if you are working on windows and on linux you can compile using simple g++ commands . Best use online IDEs available nowadays. But if you are working on a project (which doesn't seem so to be your case) prefer Visual Studio .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe below this code will help

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
int i=0;
int a[100];

while(cin>>a[i]){
    i++;
    if(cin.get()=='\n') break;
}
cout<<i;

return 0;
}
```

here you must have to aware about if user enter will enter value more then 100
as per your array `a[100]` then your logic or above program will not work and go in infinite loop

Comment: And what happens if the character you `get` is *not* a newline? Then it will be lost forever.

Comment: This doesn't work in my computer. Can you please try running and checking it again?

Comment: look out code i made some changes. and tell me if you got output or any error

Comment: here new line means enter when user press enter "\n"

Comment: How do you expect this works if you just press enter without another non-whitespace character before it?

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key tells the terminal to send the input to your program, nothing else. If you want to terminate the input you need to send end-of-file character.

On POSIX systems (like Linux and macOS) end-of-file is usually <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, on Windows it's usually <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> (on an empty line and possibly pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> after).

And as you should have guessed from the above, this has nothing to do with the *compiler*, but rather the environment (most notably the operating system).

---

On a slightly related note, your code

> for getting an array input without knowing its size previously

is seriously flawed. What happens if the user inputs more than 100 values? Then you will go out of bounds.

Better learn about [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) quickly.

Comment: Thanks. Ctrl-Z works here. I have a slight add-on. On online compilers where they give an input column, is the end-of-file character automatically added to each line of input? (because it works there without Ctrl-Z)

Comment: @PrithviVenu That you have to read the documentation, but my guess is if you enter multiple lines it will add the EOF after the last line ended.

Comment: Ah, I get you. Is there another way of getting input without size? I am asking this for competitions where the array input bounds are given.

Comment: The online compiler is non-interactive,  the input stream is preassigned. There is no EOF character involved. (Similar to redirecting a text file as stdin)

Comment: boring aswer . please give me code . learn how to aswer with other thanks